# Adicionar botão na tabela angular material

Tags: angular, tabela-html, angular-material

Como adicionar botão de editar/excluir na tabela do angular material? Aqui tem um exemplo [1].

Atualmente o código tá assim:

````
  <ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{col.field}}">

      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{col.title}} </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <ng-container>
          <div>{{element.displayData[col.field]}}</div>
        </ng-container>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
  <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
    <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div *ngIf="qtdData > perPage">
  <mat-paginator class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" appPagination [pageSizeOptions]="[perPage]" hidePageSize="true" ></mat-paginator>
</div>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdZuL.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um outro `ng-container` para criar a coluna de ações. abaixo segue um exemplo de como fazer.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{col.field}}">

      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{col.title}} </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <ng-container>
          <div>{{element.displayData[col.field]}}</div>
        </ng-container>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

  </ng-container>

<ng-container  matColumnDef="actions">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="text-center">
            Ações
          </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="text-center">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <button mat-stroked-button class="m-2" (click)="edit(row.id)" color="accent">
                Editar
              </button>
              <button mat-stroked-button class="m-2" (click)="delete(row.id)" color="warn">
                Excluir
              </button>
            </div>
          </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
  <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
    <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div *ngIf="qtdData > perPage">
  <mat-paginator class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" appPagination [pageSizeOptions]="[perPage]" hidePageSize="true" ></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Lembrando que se você adicionou um novo `ng-container` com o `matColumnDef="actions"` você precisa adicionar a string `actions` no array `displayedColumns` e modificar o `colspan="4"`na  do `No data matching the filter`

Para mais informações consulte a documentação: [`Angular Material table`](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)